# Sequelize default foreign key

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a model `Route` belongs to `Region`, when I define the associate, I thought you could just simply do the following:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Route = sequelize.define("Route", {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

  Route.associate = models => {
    Route.belongsTo(models.Region);
  };
  return Route;
};
```

With the route:

```
app.post("/api/regions/:regionId/routes", routesController.create);
```

Controller:

```
  create(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.regionId);
    return Route.create({
      title: req.body.title,
      regionId: req.params.regionId
    })
      .then(route => res.status(201).send(route))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
  },
```

But when I post to that route, I keeps getting back the route with `Null` for `regionId`. Even though I can `log` the regionId with `POST` params.

I know the fix is to add `foreignKey` as following to explicit declare to use `regionId` as foreignKey:

```
Route.associate = models => {
    Route.belongsTo(models.Region, {
      foreignKey: "regionId"
    });
  };
```

But I thought it could just default `regionId` as foreignKey without declaring it. Am I missing something?

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with sequelize, is about how are you sending your parameter on the url. Check with postman or  other software that you are catching right the `:regionId`

Comment: Like i said, it is being caught. I can print out `params` for regionId, but it is not being saved to database. It is only saved as `null`. I also posted the solution as well, but what i do not get is why foreignkey is required. On the doc, it says: "In all cases the default foreign key can be overwritten with the foreignKey option". Doesn't that imply there is a default foreign key

Comment: can you show your controller where you do the create?

Comment: I added controller!

Comment: instead of using `foreignKey:` use `as:` this also will help you when you need to do an include if you associate the same model more than once.

Comment: Could you at least read through what I am asking before answering my question? My solution works, I know `as:` would work as well. BUT my question is, why do I have to use either solution? Why is `Route.belongsTo(models.Region);` itself not working

Comment: I read that you had the solution, just trying to see if you tried other things. On my own case I have some association without specify `as`or `foreignKey `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158457/discussion-between-leogoesger-and-ellebkey).